# Angular REST response and type

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I am retrieving objects from a REST service and reusing this data troughout my application. So the way I can make the structure of these objects known at the point where the REST service retrieves the data is by using a 'type' declaration from typescript.

Now my problem arose when I returned this data to the calling component where this type is not known. So I made a "shared/models/objectname.model.ts" file where I put the 'export type' in. This works, because shared is imported in the module I am working in but it instantly did not feel right as I am not entirely sure if I should even call this a model.

I need this type definition trough my app and redifining it every time I pass the data to the next step would also not be what I want.

Is what I did "common practice" or how would this have to be resolved normally? Angulars documentation does not help me at all or my search queries arent correct as English is not my first language. Ive been searching for good practices for over an hour now but I only ever see it used in examples where the data stays in the page.

Comment: sounds like yes